# Can we find bit depth of a video in android programmatically

Tags: java, android

We can find height, width and many other attributes of a video in android using MediaMetadataRetriever class. Is there any way to find or calculate the bit depth of the video in Android programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaMetdataRetriever` class does not have any functions to find the Bit Depth at this point in time.

Comment: Is there any other library or way to calculate bit depth?